# Get reminder list with EventKit

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I want to get the list each task belongs to. How can I get it using `EventKit`?

It seems that the `EKReminder` doesn't have a property describing which list it belongs to.

Comment: please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/retrieving_events_and_reminders

Comment: In terms of `EventKit` a *list* is a calendar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for reminders, the list it belongs to is called the calendar. To further expand on that answer, you can access it like this:

`let list = reminder.calendar`

To get the list title:

`let listTitle = reminder.calendar.title`

You can even get the list color:

`let listColor = reminder.calendar.cgColor`